# Find and pause tasks playing audio in Android

Tags: java, android, audio, android-activity, task

I need to find out if any other activities (like Pandora) are open and running, and pause and resume the tasks so as to pause and resume audio.

Is this possible? If so, how do I do it?

I know there's the ability to get running tasks if you have the right permissions, but I don't know where to go from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't pause, but you *can* use another audio stream.

Use [SoundPool](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/SoundPool.html) with the ALARM thread.

Answer (score 0):

> Is this possible?

Not really. If your objective is to play some audio (e.g., a ringtone), use the audio focus methods on `AudioManager`.

Comment: How do I do this? I'm playing sound via the HTML5 Media API right now, so pausing and resuming threads would have been soooo much easier.

Comment: @StefanKendall: "How do I do this?" -- you don't. What makes you think that you have a right to attack other apps this way?

Comment: I can start some audio and shut 'em down, so that seems worse than pausing and resuming. I don't see how it's "attacking" to communicate between apps.

Right now, I'm scribbling on pandora, and that's that. I'd like not to scribble on pandora.

Comment: @StefanKendall: "I don't see how it's "attacking" to communicate between apps." -- if the app does not expose some app-specific API, it is. You are certainly welcome to download all 600,000 Android apps, determine which ones play audio, contact each of their developers to find out if they expose an API to allow arbitrary third party apps to mess with their playback, implement the logic for each of those that respond in your app, etc. Outside of audio focus APIs, any given app does not have to allow other apps to pause playback.

Comment: I don't think you understand that *by default*, all other app audio is stopped.

By default.

Comment: @StefanKendall: No, I understand that. That does not change the fact that there is no requirement for apps to implement some other sort of pause and resume mechanism, let alone any standards for its invocation. Each app will behave however its authors want in the face of some other app trying to work with the audio playback system while they are already using it. You are welcome to propose such a pause-and-resume standard, then lobby various app developers to implement it.